# Google Cloud Print Api not working

Tags: android

Hello  i am trying with the google cloud print api according to the documentation available

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appInterfaces site.

My Source code is to call the google cloud print search API is :

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String result2;
        try {
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://www.google.com/cloudprint/search?output=json");


          request.setHeader("access_token",token);

            List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("q","recent"));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type",""));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("connection_status", ""));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("use_cdd", ""));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("extra_fields", ""));


            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = null;
            try {
                formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);


            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            request.setEntity(formEntity);
            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                response = client.execute(request);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SocketException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                        .getEntity().getContent()));
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            try {
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + NL);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            result2 = sb.toString();

        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }

        Log.d("result is::", result2);

        return result2;
    }
```

Where token is the getting from the google+ login api.

I have also try to set the header with

```
request.setHeader("Authorization", "OAuth "+token);
```

But all time it is showing the Html output:

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <TITLE>User credentials required</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
 <H1>User credentials required</H1>
 <H2>Error 403</H2>
</BODY>
 </HTML>
```

Can anybody help me out regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
request.addHeader("X-CloudPrint-Proxy", "Google-JS");
request.addHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
request.addHeader("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + token);
```

Some words about awnser @revdev. This anwser also correct. But `Bearer` header should be used, if token get on login over web browser with [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?hl=ru).

`GoogleLogin auth` should be used, if token get by [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) from exists google account at device.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *Bearer* in the Authorization header, like this:

```
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
```